# Converting a file in python

Tags: python, sql, regex, file

I am using Amazon Redshift to analyze the existing compression. Unfortunately, it does not persist the data in database. I have to store the details in a file. I already have the information from database/system views about column_name and datatype.

I need to merge these information so that I can use them to create new tables with compression.

I have python script to create tables from the metadata. I need this extra information to add to it to the create table syntax.

My output text file in the following format

```
  schema_name.table_name

table_name   column_name compression_type
```

for e.g

```
abc_schema.tab1
tab1   col1 raw
tab1   col2 lzo
tab1   col3 bytedict
tab1   col4 delta32k
tab1   col5 raw
abc_schema.tab2
tab2   col1 raw
tab2   col2 lzo
tab2   col3 bytedict
tab2   col4 delta32k
tab2   col5 raw
```

I want to insert them into database table.

`insert into tab_details values (schema_name, table_name, column_name, compression_type)`.

My challenge how do I read the header, i.e schema_name.table_name and merge with the details.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Update:

I tried using python and getting an error.

```
import csv
with open ('2','r') as infile:
   reader = csv.reader(infile)
   header = next(reader)
   mydict = dict(row[:2] for row in reader if row)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #26 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Comment: The insert command is to be executed in a loop. So a starter set is when you have the schema name, then table,row,type. Each successive match is for table,row,type until you get the next schema ? Is that the actual file format in your example ? My guess is to use the `\G` last match construct if Python supports it.

Comment: It is the actual file. Can please provide me a code example.

Comment: Looks like `\G` is supported in the latest Python. I don't know Python, so the only thing I could give you is a regex to capture this data line by line. Is that enough?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Let me sort it out